# Regex for getting string between varying prefix & suffix

Tags: regex, regex-group, capturing-group

I am trying to extract a certain string from a set of filepaths that are formatted in one of two ways.

Examples:

```
Filepath A: /someprefix<DATE-TO-EXTRACT>/filename.txt
Filepath B: /someprefix<DATE-TO-EXTRACT>somesuffix/filename.txt
```

I need to capture only what is in the `<DATE-TO-EXTRACT>` placeholder. In other words, I need the text between `someprefix` and the following `/` OR the text between `someprefix` and the following `somesuffix`.

I tried the following creating a single regex pattern, but it isn't quite working for both: `.*someprefix([^/]*)(somesuffix|/).*`

The issue with the above pattern is that the `somesuffix` part is incorrectly getting included in the match. That 2nd capturing group I have clearly isn't working. Does anyone know how I can adjust my regex to only match the contents of `<DATE-TO-EXTRACT>` for both filepath formats?

Comment: It is `someprefix(.*?)(?:somesuffix|$)`

Comment: Try [`someprefix([^/]*?)(?:somesuffix)?/`](https://regex101.com/r/t2GiFI/1/)